# CompileStoryboard LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **

[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:

[ERROR] :   CompileStoryboard LaunchScreen.storyboard

[ERROR] :  (1 failure)

How to fix this? it wont run on ios device but on simulator it seems ok.
it runs on web, android and ios simulator but on ios device got this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because my project was using the newer Titanium 6.0 SDK with the `<enable-launch-screen-storyboard>true</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>`, but I was compiling against the older Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3 SDK.

If you are using Ti 6.0.1 (current latest) with a storyboard, make sure you have installed Xcode 8.2.1 and compile against the iOS 10.2 SDK.

When you are installing the app on a device using the `appc` command line, you can specify the target iOS SDK using `--ios-version 10.2`.